Putting label in Histogram in ggplot
I have below histogra musing ggplot
library(ggplot2)
n = 1000
mean = 0
sd = 1
binwidth = 0.3 # passed to geom_histogram and stat_function
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n, mean, sd))

myplot = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, mean = mean, sd = sd, binwidth = binwidth, n = n)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = binwidth, 
        colour = "white", fill = "cornflowerblue", size = 0.1)

Now I want to add one custom label at the top-middl area, but there should be some margin, say 10 points at the top of my label. I tried below
myplot+
geom_label(aes(x = mean((df$x)), y = 100), label = 'Plot with y', label.padding = unit(.7, 'lines'), fill = '#000000', color = '#ffffff', alpha = 0.2)

Is there any way to dynamically (based on data only without any hardcoding) set y = 100 to keep the label at the top with 10 points margin?

First, use annotate(geom = "label", ...) to add just one label. Using geom_label you add a label for each row of your data, i.e. you are adding 1000 labels on top of each other. Second, could you clarify how your y should be set? Should the label be placed at the top of the plot area (with some margin)?

Yes, label to be placed at the top-middle of the plot area (with some margin)

One option to place your label at the top of the plot area and having some margin would be to use annotation_custom which requires to add your label via a grob. For the latter I use gridtext::richtext_grob (as grid does not provide a labelGrob whereas ggplot2 does not export it):
library(ggplot2)
library(gridtext)
library(grid)

myplot +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = gridtext::richtext_grob(
      text = "Plot with y",
      # Place at the top with margin of 5mm
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(5, "mm"),
      # Padding around label
      padding = unit(.7, "lines"),
      gp = grid::gpar(col = "#ffffff"),
      box_gp = grid::gpar(fill = "#000000", alpha = .6),
      vjust = 1
    ),
    xmin = mean(df$x),
    xmax = mean(df$x)
  )


EDIT If you can't install any non-standard package (e.g. gridtext) one option would be to use the non-exported labelGrob from ggplot2 using ::::
myplot +
  annotation_custom(
    grob = ggplot2:::labelGrob(
      label = "Plot with y",
      # Place at the top with margin of 5mm
      y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(5, "mm"),
      # Padding around label
      padding = unit(rep(.7, 4), "lines"),
      text.gp = grid::gpar(col = "#ffffff"),
      rect.gp = grid::gpar(fill = "black", alpha = .6),
      just = "top"
    ),
    xmin = mean(df$x),
    xmax = mean(df$x)
  )



This is perfect, but I wonder if same can be achieved using standard libraries. I work in an isolated computer, so installation of non-standard libraries is problematic

See my edit for a version using the non-exported labelGrob. This way gridtext is not required (whereas grid is part of the standard libraries of any R installation, e.g. ggplot2 builds on grid).

I am getting error Error in validDetails.roundrect(x) : 'x', 'y', 'width', and 'height' must have length 1

Do you get this error when running the code I provided in my answer without any changes? And if yes, what version of ggplot2 are you using and what version of R?

R version 3.5.1. and ggplot2 3.3.5. Yes it is old version. But as I said, my system is isolated due to security issue, so am looking for basic standard functions to achieve this

I see. The functions are standard. But R and R packages evolve, some things change, bugs get fixed, ... . If I find the time I will setup a docker container with your versions of R and ggplot2.

Try with replacing padding = unit(rep(.7, 4), "lines") with padding = unit(.7, "lines"). Tested on R 3.5.1 and ggplot2 3.1.0. Using my code gave me the error you reported. But after the change it worked fine.

great!, perfectly worked!

just wondering, is there any way to increase the font size?

Sure. You can set the fontsize using e.g. text.gp = grid::gpar(col = "#ffffff", fontsize=8) for a size of 8pt. See ?grid::gpar for other graphical parameters.
